# Rules in htaccess do not work for CDN links

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have installed a separate wordpress on the /blog part of my wesbite. Recently I've tried to install bunnyCDN, all went well but I have some google indexed images and I want to put some redirects to the new CDN links, but the images are still accesible from the domain link, no redirect is made. I've also tried putting the rewrites on top of the file, but still nothing. This is my htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>


RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} uploads
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*) https://<bunnycdnlink>.b-cdn.net/$1 [R=302,NC]
```

What can be wrong?

EDIT: The htaccess provided is located in the /blog folder

Comment: There is rather little point in using a RewriteCond to check on the requested path, the RewriteRule can do that perfectly fine on its own. _"This is my htaccess file:"_ - and that is located _where_? Inside the `blog` folder, or on the root level?

Comment: It is located in the /blog folder. edit: will add to the main question

Comment: _"It is located in the /blog folder"_ - then the path RewriteRule matches against, will not start with `blog/` - the part that leads to the current directory, has already been stripped off at this point. Try `RewriteRule ^uploads/(.*) https://<bunnycdnlink>.b-cdn.net/$1 [R=302,NC]` (without any RewriteCond.)

Comment: Still doesn't work. I get what you're saying but no redirect is made whatsoever

Comment: Give us an example of a full, absolute URL that you want to redirect.

Comment: https://www.appointfix.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/follow-up-message-templates-for-clients.jpg

Comment: Okay, the `wp-content/` needs to be part of the pattern as well then of course.

Comment: Yes, but I'm wondering what else can it be, like I've tried restarting the server etc. But nothing works. Can it be from the wordpress theme? It's custom made.

Comment: Nah, that is very unlikely. Anything the theme does, can't start to happen before the request is even routed.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below line to fix it

`RewriteRule ^(blog)/[^.])$ http://bunnycdnlink>.b-cdn.net/$1 [L,R,NC]`

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer, but I've tested it with a htaccess tester and it says that the regex is not valid